# how to add local variables in fetch Api command

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, flask-mongoengine

I want to pass those arguments in my fetch command so that this information get saved in my database

```
function addItemToCart(title,price,imgSrc)
{
    console.log('starting ajax call')
                var requestOptions = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    redirect: 'follow'
                  };

                  fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/query?product=title", requestOptions)
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(result => console.log(result))
                    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Comment: get method should be used for queries, but the `post` method should be used for the updating your database,  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch for details

Comment: see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch for details, specifically : Supplying request options

Answer (score 0):

You can add a variable to strings if you put a `+` in between the variable and the string. So you wonna do this:

```
var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/query?product=' + title;
var requestOptions = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    redirect: 'follow'
                  };
fetch(url, requestOptions)
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(result => console.log(result))
                    .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Then you can have Flask parse the results using these line of code:

```
# Top
from flask import request

# View code
title = request.args.get('product')
```

Hope this helps

Ps. Keep in mind that when doing the args.get the string should be the "variable" in the url, so if you instead were to lookup an id, then you should say `www.url.com?id=15`, but you can use any word instead of the id if you want to.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question, it is just adding title to the query string - they want to know how to post the data passed to their function back to server, so it can be stored.

Comment: Oh... I misunderstood the problem. But in such case they should send a post request to the flask which then on post request should retrieve the data using request.args.post('produkt') and then store it into the database

Comment: oh so i should just use post request in my routes to retrieve the data and store it in my database?